# matrix&eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in M_n(C)$ and $A^{-1}=A^*$. Prove that the eigenvalues of A have the modul equal with one.

P.S. I know that this is a property well-known, but I couldn't find a demonstration for it.

Answer (score 2):

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then 
$$
\|Av\|^2 = (Av)^*(Av) = (\lambda v)^*(\lambda v) = |\lambda|^2 \|v\|^2
$$
However, in this case we can also write
$$
\|Av\|^2 = v^*A^*Av = v^*v = \|v\|^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Then $\lambda\neq0$ because $A$ is invertible. Let $v$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $A.v=\lambda v$. Therefore$$A^{-1}.v=A^{-1}.\left(\frac1\lambda.\lambda.v\right)=\frac1\lambda.(A^{-1}.(\lambda v))=\frac1\lambda v.$$But $A^{-1}=A^*$ and $A^*.v=\overline\lambda.v$. Therefore…

Comment: how you obtain this: $A^*.v=\overline\lambda.v$?

Comment: @CosminCretu How do you define $A^*$?

Comment: the transpose of its cofactor matrix

Comment: @CosminCretu So, it is the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$! I am sorry; I thought that it was the adjoint matrix. But then the statement is false. If$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&7\end{pmatrix},$$then $A^{-1}=A^*$, but the eigenvalues of $A$ are $4\pm\sqrt{15}$.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ and $A^*$ are $1\over\lambda$ and $\lambda^*$ respectively. So we can write: ${1\over\lambda}=\lambda^*$ or $\lambda=e^{i\theta}$